# cannot find OnInit in typescript during implementation

Tags: angular

I am working on a sample project with a loginComponent, I need to implement OnInit in my class when i try to add the OnInit i am getting the following error

> [ts] cannot find OnInit

Here is my code

```
export class loginComponent implements OnInit{

 ngOnInit():all{

    }
}
```

How to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `ngOnInit(): any`

Comment: i tried it but still getting the same error

Comment: There's no need to replicate answers in questions, and we don't use [solved] title amendments here. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to import it from "@angular/core". Also, you don't need to return anything from this method, so you can safely skip returning type.

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class loginComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```