# Angular 2: Cannot find ngOnInit/ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, implements, ngoninit, ngondestroy

NOTE: I found the article [cannot find OnInit in typescript during implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139698/cannot-find-oninit-in-typescript-during-implementation) but the code below is already importing `OnInit`/`OnDestroy`.

All the examples I've found (e.g., [Using Route Parameters](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html)) indicate adding the `implements OnInit`/`OnDestroy` clause to the class definition and including the `ngOnInit`/`ngOnDestroy` methods when subscribing to obtain a parameter from the route -- which the code is doing.

However, VS2017 reports the error "incorrectly implements OnInit/OnDestroy" for the clause and reports the error "Cannot find ngOnInit/ngOnDestroy" for the functions.

If I remove the `implements` clause and comment the `ngOnInit`/`ngOnDestroy` functions (leaving only the code in the body of the `ngOnInit`), the code works; it successfully obtains the parameter from the route parameters.

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'submission',
    templateUrl: './submission.component.html'
})
export class SubmissionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private baseUrl: string;
    private http: Http;
    private route: ActivatedRoute;
    private sub: any;

    public caseId: string;
    public submission: Submission;

    constructor(http: Http, route: ActivatedRoute, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.route = route;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                this.caseId = params['caseId'];

                // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
            });
        }

        ngOnDestroy() {
            this.sub.unsubscribe();
        }

        this.get(this.caseId);
    }

    public get(caseId: string) {
        var url = this.baseUrl + 'api/Submission/GetSubmission?caseId=' + caseId;
        this.http.get(url).subscribe(result => {
            this.submission = result.json() as Submission;
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    public put() {
        var url = this.baseUrl + 'api/Submission/PutSubmission';
        this.http.put(url, this.submission).subscribe(result => {
            this.submission = result.json() as Submission;
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` should be outside the constructor. Like this:

```
// imports ...

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class SubmissionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // ...

  constructor( /* ... */ ) {
    // ...
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // ...
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see from your code that ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy are inside constructor, so if you take it outside you should be fine.

Code example:

```
constructor(http: Http, route: ActivatedRoute, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.http = http;
    this.route = route;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.caseId = params['caseId'];

      this.get(this.caseId);

      // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Generally, when adding ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy you should always check these steps:

1. Check that you have imported OnInit and OnDestroy from 'angular/core'
2. Then add them to class
3. Add these functions

   ```
   import { OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
   export class ComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
     ngOnInit(){}

     ngOnDestroy(){}
   }
   ```